# Filter object based on condition

Tags: javascript

I have an object as

```
sports={
   "cricket":true,
   "football":true,
   "tennis":false
}
```

I want to filter all the sports which are true into an array like `[cricket,football]`

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, the keys have to be surrounded by double quotes.  Also, can you share some code you have tried?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Iterate over the properties of the object, check their values and if `true` push the properties (their names) into an array.

Comment: This should do it. `Object.keys(sports).filter(x=> sports[x])` First get the keys as an array, then filter where the value is truthy.

Comment: @David784 your comment is an answer and should be posted as one - it would get my upvote since that's the easiest solution, much less complicated than the existing ones.

Comment: @David784 thanx..that worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

follow above code returns keys of true value in array like [cricket,football]

```
const sports = {
  cricket: true,
  football: true,
  tennis: false,
};

const result = Object.keys(sports).filter((current) => {
  return sports[current];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for...in structure:

```js
sports={
   cricket:true,
   football:true,
   tennis:false
}
const result = []
for(const sport in sports) {
 if (sports[sport]) result.push(sport)
}
console.log(result)
```

more info about for...in:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: No need for something so convoluted when you have `Array.filter` and `Object.keys`

Answer (score 1):

```
var sports_arr = Object.keys(sports);
var tmp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sports_arr.length && sports[sports_arr[i]]; i++)
  tmp.push(sports_arr[i]);
```

Comment: No need for something so convoluted when you have `Array.filter`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so:

```js
const sports = {
   cricket:true,
   football:true,
   tennis:false,
};

console.log(Object.entries(sports).filter(([key, value]) => value).map(([key, value]) => key));
```

`Object.entries()` returns an array with key-value pairs:

```
[
  ['cricket', true],
  ['football', true],
  ['tennis', false],
]
```

You can then check the second element on each entry to filer out the ones that are `false`:

```
[
  ['cricket', true],
  ['football', true],
]
```

And then use map to keep only the first element:

```
[
  'cricket',
  'football',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As posted by @David784 in the comments, this is the simplest solution. No need to complicate it any further:

```js
const sports = {
   cricket:true,
   football:true,
   tennis:false,
};

const result = Object.keys(sports).filter(key => sports[key]);
console.log(result);
```

Merely get an array of the keys (`Object.keys(sports)`) and then discard the ones for which the value isn't `true` with a `.filter()`.